# How is intonation set on acoustic guitar

Tags: intonation

How do you alter the intonation on an acoustic guitar, I have nearly always played electric but more recently bought a Gibson Songwriter which I cannot put down and I have hardly played my Les Paul. Is this a professional job or something I could tackle

Answer (score 6):

On an electric guitar you set the intonation by moving the bridge saddles closer to or further away from the nut. On an acoustic guitar you file a little bevel in the top of the bridge saddle so that the string crosses the saddle  either closer to, or further away from the nut. If you buy  a couple of saddle 'blanks' (of bone or plastic) you can just set the original saddle aside and experiment with the blanks. Then, if you happen to botch the job, you just re install the original and go see a luthier.